# Paypal (payflow) returnurl change Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, paypal-payflow-pro

I have 2 websites both using same magento 2.4.2 platform and template. I use Payflow Pro for payment checkout. One appears to be operating correctly. But the other hangs when waiting for Paypal feedback.
The only difference in my Debug log for the payment is the returnurl, errorurl, and cancelurl
The website that displays result of payment (ie 'payment has been declined notification') does NOT have the index.php in the 3 response urls. The website that hangs and gives no feedback has the index.php in the urls, like example below.

```
'returnurl' => 'https://domain.com/index.php/paypal/transparent/redirect/',
'errorurl' => 'https://domain.com/index.php/paypal/transparent/redirect/',
'cancelurl' => 'https://domain.com/index.php/paypal/transparent/redirect/',
```

where can i find the code to get rid of the index.php in this url. Then i can see if this is what is causing the issue. Does anyone know if the index.php will make a significant difference in why my cart is hanging?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the store switcher that caused payflow issues.

The store switcher was adding store info to the redirect

paypal/transparent/redirect/

So I added paypal/* under pages to exclude for store switcher.

This allowed the page complete, paypal/transparent/redirect/ could not understand the added store information. Hope this helps someone that has a never completing PayFlow checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have added paypal/* ? Could you please share me file location ?
I am getting same issue in Payflow link Credit card payment. It's not redirecting checkout success page after payment